# How can I access an object in another method?

Tags: java, object

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class employeePayReport
{
    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String> > console = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    static int currState = 1;
    public employeePayReport() {
        this.console = console; 
        String[] record ={employee.name(),employee.hours(),employee.sales(),employee.rate(), employee.weeklySalary()}; //error: Undeclared Variable: employee (error for all the elements of the array) 
        record.add(employee.name());
        //how to connect this object to the object created in employeeType method
        console.add(record); //error: incompatible types: java.lang.String[] cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
    }
    public static void print(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t  Name                  Class      Hours        Sales       Rate              Weekly Pay");
        System.out.println();
        // I have to add coordinates of the array list 
        System.out.println("\t  ======================================================================================");
        // I have to add coordinates of the array list 
        System.out.println("\t  ======================================================================================");
        // I have to add coordinates of the array list 
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void employeeType(){
        System.out.println("Enter field type- "); 
        System.out.println("1 - Salaried Employee"); 
        System.out.println("2 - Hourly Employees"); 
        System.out.println("3 - Commission Based Employees"); 
        int type = sc.nextInt();
        if(type == 1){
            salariedEmployees employee = new salariedEmployees(); 
        }else if (type == 2){
            hourlyEmployees employee = new hourlyEmployees();
        }else if (type == 3){
            commissionedEmployees employee = new commissionedEmployees();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Select valid type"); 
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
//I have to edit this method...
            while(currState == 1){
                print();
                System.out.println("Enter a name: "); 
                String name = sc.next();
                employeeType(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

If you look at my `employeePayReport` constructor, I am getting an error for all the employee variable. The error says that I haven't declared the variable employee. I want to connect this variable to the object I created in the `employeeType` method. How do I give access to the object created `employee` to my constructor `employeePayReport`?

Comment: pass it in to the constructor!

Comment: declare the employee variable as class

Comment: But my `employee` object can have 3 different classes `salariedEmployees` \ `hourlyEmployees`  \ `commissionedEmployees `  (determined in my `employeeType` method). In that case, what should be my data type?

Comment: ...and do the classes of type `salariedEmployees`, `hourlyEmployees`, and `commissionedEmployees` ALL have these fields in COMMON? `name, hours, sales, employee, weeklySalary` If so, do they all DERIVE from the same BASE CLASS?...or do they all possibly implement the same INTERFACE?  If so, then you pass "employee" to the constructor using that common type. If not, then you've got a bad design and need to re-think your program.

Comment: the type of employee should be the parent class of your salariedEmployees, hourlyEmployees and commissionedEmployees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to you to create an `abstract` `class` Employee that have the common attributes with your three other classes `salariedEmployees`, `hourlyEmployees`, and `commissionedEmployees` and have also getters and setters like:

```
public abstract class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String hours;
    private String sales;
    private String rate;
    private String weeklySalary;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    .
    .//getters/setters
    .
}
```

then create your other three classes that extends this class like :

```
public class commissionedEmployees extends Employee{
    //specific attribute 
}
```

And As @OldProgrammer said in comment, in the EmployeePayReport class you can declare your Employee class as Constructor parameter :

```
public EmployeePayReport(Employee employee) {
        this.console = console; // does not make sense you assign the console to it's self
        String[] record ={employee.getName(),employee.getHours(),employee.getName(),employee.getRate(), employee.getWeeklySalary()}; //error: Undeclared Variable: employee (error for all the elements of the array) 
        //record.add(employee.getName()+""); // you can't do that because does not have function add
        //how to connect this object to the object created in employeeType method
        
        //to avoid this error you can use Arrays.asList(record) to convert array to list
        console.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(record))); //error: incompatible types: java.lang.String[] cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
}
```

**Nb : I explained the errors that you got in the comments**